# discord.py announce command

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to get my announce command to send the response to the announcements channel but I don't want to use channel id since I'm building the bot for multiple servers and prefer to keep things simple.

Unfortunately, it's not working.. here is my current code.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Announce(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client


    @commands.command(name="Announce", aliases=["A", "a", "announce", "Ann", "ann", "ANN"])
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
    async def _announce(self, ctx, *, message):
        """Sends an announcement via the bot
        Alt     : a, A, ANN, Ann, ann, announce
        Usage   : [ann]ounce <message>"""
        for channel in ctx.guild.channels:
            if str(channel) == "announcements":
                await ctx.message.delete()
                embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.dark_gold(), timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
                embed.set_author(name="Announcement", icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
                embed.add_field(name=f"Sent by {ctx.message.author}", value=str(message), inline=False)
                embed.set_thumbnail(url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
                embed.set_footer(text=self.client.user.name, icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
                await ctx.message.add_reaction(emoji="✅")
                await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)


    @_announce.error
    async def _announce_error(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
            embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.dark_red(), timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
            embed.set_author(name="Error", icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
            embed.add_field(name="Command Failed", value="Please pass in all required arguments.")
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
            embed.set_footer(text=self.client.user.name, icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
            await ctx.message.add_reaction(emoji="⚠")
            await ctx.message.author.send(embed=embed)

        elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
            embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.dark_red, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
            embed.set_author(name="Error", icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
            embed.add_field(name="Access Denied", value="You do not have permission to use this command")
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
            embed.set_footer(text=self.client.user.name, icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
            await ctx.message.add_reaction(emoji="⛔")
            await ctx.message.author.send(embed=embed)

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Announce(client))
```

I've tried to get it to work as this

```
@commands.command(name="Announce", aliases=["A", "a", "announce", "Ann", "ann", "ANN"])
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
    async def _announce(self, ctx, *, message, member):
        """Sends an announcement via the bot
        Alt     : a, A, ANN, Ann, ann, announce
        Usage   : [ann]ounce <message>"""
        for channel in ctx.member.guild.channels:
            if str(channel) == "announcements":
                await ctx.message.delete()
                embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.dark_gold(), timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
                embed.set_author(name="Announcement", icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
                embed.add_field(name=f"Sent by {ctx.message.author}", value=str(message), inline=False)
                embed.set_thumbnail(url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
                embed.set_footer(text=self.client.user.name, icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
                await ctx.message.add_reaction(emoji="✅")
                await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)


    @_announce.error
    async def _announce_error(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
            embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.dark_red(), timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
            embed.set_author(name="Error", icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
            embed.add_field(name="Command Failed", value="Please pass in all required arguments.")
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
            embed.set_footer(text=self.client.user.name, icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
            await ctx.message.add_reaction(emoji="⚠")
            await ctx.message.author.send(embed=embed)

        elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
            embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.dark_red, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
            embed.set_author(name="Error", icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
            embed.add_field(name="Access Denied", value="You do not have permission to use this command")
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
            embed.set_footer(text=self.client.user.name, icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
            await ctx.message.add_reaction(emoji="⛔")
            await ctx.message.author.send(embed=embed)
```

However this doesn't work either. Any help would be much appreciated.
I prefer to use channel names rather than channel IDs to make things simpler and reduce the amount of code I have to put in.

I'm using discord.py rewrite if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will just point out within your approach `channel` is a channel object, see [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel) so to get yours working it would need to be `str(channel.name)` due to oop. (Object oriented programming)

However, let me introduce a contender. `discord.utils.get`, see [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get), can be used to accomplish what you want easily.

```py
@commands.command()
async def announce(self, ctx):
    # Find a channel from the guilds `text channels` (Rather then voice channels)
    # with the name announcements
    channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.text_channels, name="announcements")
    if channel: # If a channel exists with the name

                embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.dark_gold(), timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
                embed.set_author(name="Announcement", icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
                embed.add_field(name=f"Sent by {ctx.message.author}", value=str(message), inline=False)
                embed.set_thumbnail(url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
                embed.set_footer(text=self.client.user.name, icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
                await ctx.message.add_reaction(emoji="✅")
                await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

We want to send to our `channel` object rather then the same channel we sent the command in, also removed us deleting the command being called otherwise adding the emoji will error. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I just had to edit my imports for it. `from discord.utils import get` had to be changed to `import discord.utils`.